# Selecting a value from a <span> type dropdown box with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a need to select one of three values (1 column unit, 2 column unit or 3 column unit) in different test cases, from the following code:

```
  <div class="addUnits">
   <span id="addDropdown" class="addDropdown">Add unit to layout</span>
   <ul id="addUnitCombo" style="display: none;">
      <li>
         <a class="addColumnUnit addOneCol" href="">1 column unit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="addColumnUnit addTwoCol" href="">2 columns unit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a class="addColumnUnit addThreeCol" href="">3 columns unit</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I understand how to retrieve the values and click on them from a Select, but this is a Span so will not allow this.  It is not a traditional dropdown box and the 3 values only become selectable (in manual operation) when

```
<span id="addDropdown" class="addDropdown">Add unit to layout</span>
```

...is hovered over.

Any idea how I can select and click one of the other values?

Comment: Which Selenium binding are you using - ex Ruby, Python, etc?

Comment: You can select any element using find element by XPath (syntax depends on your binding). With XPath you can select the span element using `//div[@class='addUnits']//span` and the descendant `a` element containing `addTwoCol` with `//div[@class='addUnits']//a[contains(@class, 'addTwoCol')]`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the HTML, you can see it's not a normal dropdown element, which is usually an `<input>` tag. If you're seeing a dropdown being rendered in the browser, perhaps it's a custom dropdown implementation in JavaScript (Note the `display: none;`, the values in there may just be 'holders' for JavaScript to access elsewhere.)

I would suggest carefully examining exactly what HTML element(s) are used to draw and implement the dropdown, select the one you want, and then send a click to it.